# Question marks in ls metadata output?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, ls, ext4, file-metadata

I was monitoring a directory containing downloads from Google Chrome with `ls -la` and got this in the output:

```
-?????????  ? ?     ?            ?            ? 'Unconfirmed 784300.crdownload'
```

I've never seen such question marks in the output.

There were other files in the directory with normal metadata output. When I ran `ls -la` again the output was all normal; the file still had the same name but the metadata was now visible. Later when the download finished the file was renamed to its final name, as expected.

I checked `/var/log/syslog` and `dmesg` output and didn't see any kernel messages.

I wonder if I hit some race condition? I wonder if there is a brief moment after the file is first created where the information is not yet available?

ext4 filesystem with seemingly standard mount options (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro), 5.4.0-59-generic kernel on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a (temporary?) file which had disappeared in the time between `ls` reading its directory entry and trying to get the metadata from its inode.

You can reproduce that by stopping `ls` just before it calls `lstat` on a file, removing that file, and then letting it continue:

```
$ mkdir dir; touch dir/file
$ gdb -q ls
Reading symbols from ls...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) br __lxstat
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4200
(gdb) r -l dir
...
Breakpoint 1, __GI___lxstat (vers=1, name=0x7fffffffdfca "dir",
    buf=0x55555557c538) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64/lxstat.c:34
(gdb) c
...
Breakpoint 1, __GI___lxstat (vers=1, name=0x7fffffffd3f0 "dir/file",
    buf=0x55555557c538) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64/lxstat.c:34
...
(gdb) shell rm dir/file
(gdb) c
...
/usr/bin/ls: cannot access 'dir/file': No such file or directory
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? file
```

> wonder if I hit some race condition?

Kind of, but not really. It's simply the fact that `ls` does not hold a lock on the filesystem while it does its stuff ;-)

In any case, this is **not** a symptom of filesystem corruption or anything like that.