# What does the output `d?????????` in `ls -l` mean?

Tags: permissions, directory, ls, tree

What is the situation why `ls -l` returns a list of subdirectories in the form below?

```
 d????????? ? ? ? ?       ? Subdirectory
```

A `tree` launched on that directory returns `0 directories, 0 files` for example. The system seems to know the name of the subdirectory but cannot find it.
Which missing link confuses `ls`?

**Late note.** On directories, thus not on files, see also:

- [Linux local directory permissions as question-marks for non-root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393598/linux-local-directory-permissions-as-question-marks-for-non-root)

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/217676/692743

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/393598/170373 https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/542422/170373 https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/158443/170373

Comment: re. that late note, I'm not sure what you mean with "thus not files". If the user doesn't have `x` access to the directory, they can't read the permission bits of the contained entries, regardless of if those entries are files or directories. On some systems, they _can_ get the type though, so `ls` can show `d?????????`, or `-?????????`. The answers in that linked question mention the same permissions issue that's also mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have read, but not execute/search permissions to the containing directory.

Easy to reproduce with:

```
mkdir -p foo/bar; chmod -x foo; ls -l foo
ls: cannot access 'foo/bar': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? bar
```

On Linux and BSD, `ls` is able to get that it's a directory from the `d_type` field of the [directory entry](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Directory-Entries.html), but not much more.

That may also happen in other situations where `ls` is not able to access the actual inode, but only the directory entry which points to it (as when the file or directory inode has disappeared before `ls` was able to `stat()` it -- see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/675373/325065), or when the it's an inaccessible mount point -- see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607690/what-does-means-in-ls-l-output?noredirect=1)).